# Disable preview of dead key characters

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

I recently installed Ubuntu 21.10, and I use a Latin American Layout keyboard. I noticed that anytime I want to use special characters that required the key to be pressed twice it will show a preview after the first event. For example:

[image]
[image]
[image]

After the second event occurs, it is shown as normal. This behavior mess with any software where the text is automatically enclosed between a pair of a character. For example, in WebStorm, VSCode, etc, when I need to enclose a piece of code between `, the first key event deletes the selected text.

[image]

Is there any way to change this?

**Edit**

Using `xev` I pressed `Alt gr` + `^`, released `^`, pressed `^` and then released both.

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
    root 0x1e5, subw 0x0, time 34853384, (321,160), root:(4261,846),
    state 0x10, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
    root 0x1e5, subw 0x0, time 34853545, (321,160), root:(4261,846),
    state 0x90, keycode 48 (keysym 0xfe52, dead_circumflex), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5e) "^"
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: True

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
    root 0x1e5, subw 0x0, time 34853656, (321,160), root:(4261,846),
    state 0x90, keycode 48 (keysym 0xfe52, dead_circumflex), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5e) "^"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
    root 0x1e5, subw 0x0, time 34853847, (321,160), root:(4261,846),
    state 0x90, keycode 48 (keysym 0xfe52, dead_circumflex), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5e) "^"
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: True

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
    root 0x1e5, subw 0x0, time 34853847, (321,160), root:(4261,846),
    state 0x90, keycode 0 (keysym 0x5e, asciicircum), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 15
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5e) "^"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
    root 0x1e5, subw 0x0, time 34853932, (321,160), root:(4261,846),
    state 0x90, keycode 48 (keysym 0xfe52, dead_circumflex), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5e) "^"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
    root 0x1e5, subw 0x0, time 34854065, (321,160), root:(4261,846),
    state 0x90, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Do you want the accents to be dead keys or not? If Vscode interprets the dead key differently from entering the character directly, that's a problem with Vscode, not an OS-level problem. If you want to change the keyboard configuration to not have dead keys, that's an OS-level problem. And by the way this has nothing to do with a “preview”: it's about whether pressing the accent key inserts the character, or waits for a second character to maybe insert an accented letter.

Comment: Before the OS reinstallation, when I was using Ubuntu 20.04, pressing a dead key (didn't know that this is the name of this kind of key) show nothing on the screen. Only after a second event does it show something. For example, pressing `^` only once will show nothing on screen, only after I press again `^` it is displayed. But in my case, pressing `^` will show the character underlined. This happens system-wide, not only on those apps. Once again, on Ubuntu 20.04, the effect showed for the string text, on the gif, never happened to me.

Comment: Maybe it's a feature of a Gnome input method and not of the keyboard configuration. Please run the program `xev` from a terminal and type `^`.  You'll see many lines, and in particular a `KeyPress event` and two lines below something like `state …, keycode … (keysym …, asciicircum), …`, or maybe `dead_circumflex` instead of `asciicircum`. Please post the whole paragraph starting with this `KeyPress` line.

Comment: I updated the questions with the `xev` output